# W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2632): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection

Tags: android

When i'm trying to log in **linkedIn** through my application .i am getting warning W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2632): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection.

When call intent this warning is getting

```
05-19 07:44:07.922: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(2632): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

can anyone help me out here ?